How to determine the ideal number of components for PLSR using RMSE?
I would like to determine a non-visual, numeric based approach to determine the ideal number of components for my PLSR model.
There are 10 components in the model for 1 target variable.
If I simply take the minimum RMSE, there is a chance that this will lead to overfitting.
The solution I have created is to normalize all of the RMSE relative to the initial RMSE value.
Then, I evaluate the RMSE improvement per component count as a percentage. If the RMSE at a component is more than .2% of a decrease compared to the previous component count RMSE, and there is less than a .2% decrease across the remaining component counts RMSE, the current component count is decided upon as the ideal component count.
Here is an image showing the decrease in RMSE plotted against the number of components in the model.

relative decrease with an initial value of 1:
[1,
0.004658795584743515,
0.004425848412019989,
0.0038956684834532893,
0.002636942279393668,
-0.003304257338957214,
0.0005941970353721279,
-0.005115285683331376,
0.006326001921934667,
-0.0004789479534198631]
At component number 6 there is a negative relative RMSE value, indicating that component number 5 is a local minimum. If we evaluate the remaining component count's RMSE values, there is less than a decrease of .2%.
Would this be an approach to determine the ideal number of components?
Additionally, when the increase from the first component to the last component only sees a total increase of 3% relative to the initial RMSE, is it justifiable to select the first component only, since this would reduce overfitting at minimal cost of generalization?
